# Haupt- und Nebensatz "Ich weiß, dass..." Definition?

Tags: comma, subordinate-clause

Ich habe ein Problem mit der Definition des Hauptsatzes: 
"Der Hauptsatz kann alleine stehen".

Im Satz "Ich glaube, sie ist Zuhause", ist der Hauptsatz: "sie ist Zuhause" und der Nebensatz "Ich glaube" . Der Hauptsatz kann ganz klar alleine stehen und wir nehmen an, dass "Ich glaube" nicht alleine stehen kann.

Im Satz "Ich glaube, dass sie Zuhause ist", ist der Hauptsatz "Ich glaube" und der Nebensatz "dass sie Zuhause ist". Hier behaupten wir, dass "Ich glaube" alleine stehen kann und "dass sie Zuhause ist" nicht.

Wieso darf im zweiten Satz "Ich glaube" als Hauptsatz fungieren. Im ersten Beispiel aber nicht ? Es ist der identische Satz.

Comment: Willkommen bei GermanSE, und danke für eine gute erste Frage!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So merkwürdig es sich auf den ersten Blick auch anhören mag, ist im Satz "Ich glaube, sie ist zu Hause" der Hauptsatz "Ich glaube, sie ist zu Hause".

Die Erklärung liegt darin, dass der im Hauptsatz **enthaltene** Nebensatz "sie ist zu Hause" das Objekt zum Prädikat "glaube" darstellt. Der Hauptsatz ist also nicht wie von Dir angenommen "Ich glaube" - dieser Satz würde so etwas bedeuten wie "Ich glaube an Gott" oder "Ich haben einen Glauben" - , sondern eben "Ich glaube *etwas*" mit *etwas* = "sie ist zu Hause". Der Satz ist also äquivalent zu dem zweiten von Dir angeführten Satz "Ich glaube, dass sie zu Hause ist"; der Hauptsatz **enthält** den Nebensatz als Objekt.

Siehe auch den Wikipedia-Artikel [Nebensatz](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nebensatz) an den Stellen, wo das Wort "Objekt" auftaucht.

Zum Thema "Zuhause" vs. "zu Hause" siehe diese [Duden-Erklärung](https://www.duden.de/sprachwissen/sprachratgeber/zu-Hause-oder-Zuhause).

Comment: Danke für die ausführliche Erklärung. Das ergibt Sinn.

Comment: Aber eine Frage dazu: ist "sie ist zu Hause", dann ein Hauptsatz oder ein Nebensatz? Weil er kann ja alleine stehen, aber eigentlich ist er ja das Objekt und obwohl er die Anforderungen erfüllt ein Hauptsatz zu sein, erfüllt er die Funktion nicht. Oder?

Comment: In dem Satz "Ich glaube, sie ist zu Hause" ist "sie ist zu Hause" ein Nebensatz. Dieser Satz könnte aber natürlich getrennt stehen. Einfach nur "Sie ist zu Hause". Dann wäre er ein Hauptsatz.